# IE8 array filter() does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-8, array-difference

I came to know that in IE8 array filter function is not supported.
After looking for help on internet I found this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

It suggest that IE8 will work using above code.

HTML Code:

```
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="calculateDiff()">Calculate</a>
</body>
```

JS Code:

```
function calculateDiff() {
    var arr1 = new Array(1, 2, 3);
    var arr2 = new Array(3, 4, 5);
    var res = arr1.diff(arr2);

    alert(res);
}


Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {

    if(!Array.prototype.filter) {
        alert("not supported");
        Array.prototype.filter = function(fun) {
            "use strict";

            if(this == null)
                throw new TypeError();

            var t = Object(this);
            var len = t.length >>> 0;
            if(typeof fun != "function")
                throw new TypeError();

            var res = [];
            var thisp = arguments[1];
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if(i in t) {
                    var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
                    if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
                        res.push(val);
                }
            }

            return res;
        };
    }
    else {
        alert("supported");
        return this.filter(function(i) {
            return !(a.indexOf(i) > -1);
        });
    }
}
```

I have implemented the solution in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7LFMA/

What is wrong in the code? Why doesn't it work ?

Comment: You should split out the check / creation of .filter() on your Array - or you'll be trying to call it every time .diff() is called, you only need to do it once. - there are polyfills for all the missing ES5 methods - take a look here: http://www.calormen.com/polyfill/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running `diff` for the first time, it will only alert `"Not Supported"`, install the `filter` polyfill but *do nothing*. It just returns `undefined`, instead of diffing like it is supposed to do.

Remove the `else`, or better just move the `filter` installation outside the `diff` function - it is not to be a part of it (e.g. in terms of closure, though modern engines will care about this).

Also, IE8 does not support the `indexOf` method, you will need to put [this compat shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) in as well.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement) {…};

if (!Array.prototype.filter)
    Array.prototype.filter = function(fun) {…};

Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {
        return !(a.indexOf(i) > -1);
    });
};

function calculateDiff() {
    var arr1 = new Array(1, 2, 3);
    var arr2 = new Array(3, 4, 5);
    var res = arr1.diff(arr2);

    alert(res);
}
```

Comment: As I would have said if I had had the time :) +1

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does not support indexOf for arrays - you still use it in the code so once you implement filter, it DOES exist and then IE8 will try to use indexOf.

In your code you do not actually APPLY the filter once you call DIFF but once you do that,  you also need to implement indexOf

[MDN Array indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)